# Maven not packaging JAX-WS Web service into WAR

Tags: web-services, maven, jboss

I'm building a Web service application to a JBoss (or Wildfly) server. Inside of it, it calls another Web services.  I use Maven for dependency, build and tests. My POM file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>[GROUPID]</groupId>
        <artifactId>DocGen</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>[GROUPID]</groupId>
    <artifactId>DocGenWS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>DocGenData</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>EA3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>DocGenWS</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </plugin> 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin> 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.12</version>
                </plugin> 
            </plugins>  
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <showwarnings>true</showwarnings>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.nicetech.tigo.docgen.ws.DocGen</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>           
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <protocol>Xsoap1.2</protocol>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <inlineSchemas>true</inlineSchemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wsimport-iface</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>sso_wsefactura.asmx.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <packageName>gt.com.megaprint.webservice</packageName>
                            <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wsimport-notification</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlUrls>
                                <wsdlUrl>http://wlstest-srv.tigo.com.gt:8011/TIGOAPIServicios/SendNotificationRI/ProxyServices/SendNotificationRIPS_?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <packageName>gt.com.tigo.notification</packageName>
                            <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-code/src</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

My generated WSDL is located at `target/jaxws/wsgen/wsdl` with its schema, but it is not included in the `WAR` package generated. When I deploy it to JBoss, the Webservices tab is empty, showing no WS in the package.  I was using ANT and it had no issue, but the dependency management and automatic builds were a living hell.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: WSgen output

```
warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
Note:   ap round: 1
[ProcessedMethods Class: com.nicetech.tigo.docgen.ws.DocGen]
[should process method: emitirDocumentoElectronico hasWebMethods: true ]
[endpointReferencesInterface: false]
[declaring class has WebSevice: true]
[returning: true]
[WrapperGen - method: emitirDocumentoElectronico(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],com.nicetech.tigo.docgen.ws.obj.EmitirDocumentoEncabezado,com.nicetech.tigo.docgen.ws.obj.EmitirDocumentoOpcional,com.nicetech.tigo.docgen.ws.obj.EmitirDocumentoDetalle)]
[method.getDeclaringType(): com.nicetech.tigo.docgen.ws.DocGen]
[requestWrapper: com.nicetech.tigo.docgen.ws.jaxws.EmitirDocumentoElectronico]
[ProcessedMethods Class: java.lang.Object]
com\nicetech\tigo\docgen\ws\jaxws\EmitirDocumentoElectronico.java
com\nicetech\tigo\docgen\ws\jaxws\EmitirDocumentoElectronicoResponse.java
Note:   ap round: 2
```